# Как сделать уже созданное окно "Выше"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.8

(Python 3.8, tkinter)
Здравствуйте, это мой первый вопрос. Я только начал свой путь в программировании, и у меня возникла одна проблема...
Имеется "база" Tk, на которой есть кнопка, запускающая окно(смотри ниже).
Имеется окно Toplevel с полями для ввода и кнопкой.
В случае, если, к примеру, поля ввода пусты и пользователь нажимает кнопку - вылезает messagebox.showinfo(с необх. информацией). После закрытия messagebox, главным (// поверх всех окон) становится "база" Tk. Есть ли такая команда, чтобы сделать окно Toplevel выше, не перестраивая его? (Ради удобства и сохранения уже введённой информации).
P.S. Немного о проблеме: окно Toplevel небольшое, открывается по центру экрана. И после закрытия messagebox "база" Tk его перекрывает, что пользователь может даже и не узнать, что у него осталось открытое окно Toplevel и создать новое(не удобно).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то ваш ответ - большущий костыль. Для решения вашей проблемы есть параметр у `messagebox`. Этот параметр после закрытия Диалогового окна переносит фокус на родительское окно(которое вы укажете в нём). Вот пример его использования:

```
messagebox.showerror('ОШБИКА', 'Введён неправильный пароль', parent = Toplevel)
```

В данном случае я вызываю Диалоговое окно ошибки. Первый параметр, который я передал - Заголовок Диалогового окна, второй - текст в самом окне, третий - имя родительского окна. Если же вы делаете окна классами, то просто пропишите `Toplevel()`.

PS Toplevel - имя моего окна `tk.Toplevel`, у вас оно может быть другим

Answer (score 1):

Вот один из вариантов решения:
(название окна).wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
Но, как верно сказали в комментариях, это большой костыль, так как окно ВСЕГДА выше других.
Было найдено и другое, более приемлемое и удобное решение:
(название окна).lift()

Comment: Как я понял у вас Диалоговое окно переносит фокус на Главное окно? Если это так, то это не решение, а большой костыль, т.к. теперь ваше окно `Toplevel` будет всегда поверх других

Comment: Да, вы правы, это огромный костыль. Отредактировал ответ, так как нашёл наиболее удобное и подходящее для меня решение.